# How to get list of SMTP servers?

Tags: python, email, dns, smtp

I have an email address like: `example@free.fr`. I want to get what is the SMTP server that this email is connected to.

For this I need to know who the mail provider is by looking at the [MX records](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MX_record) of the domain.

**Example:**

```
import dns.resolver
domain = 'free.fr'
for x in dns.resolver.resolve(domain, 'MX'):
    print(x.to_text())
```

With the MX records (MX records is for incoming email not outgoing) for the domain `free.fr`, you have to choose the SMTP server according to that.

One solution is to check against some database containing the SMTP servers for all the email providers (linked to their MX records).

How can I get an exhaustive list of SMTP servers?

Comment: `I want to get what is the SMTP server that this email is connected to`, what do you want to use the SMTP servers addresses for? To check where to deliver a particular email or where it came from? The outgoing servers for a domain(generally part of the SPF records of the domain) might be totally different from their incoming servers so the MX records won't have those.

Comment: "One solution is to check against some database containing the SMTP servers for all the email providers" - the database containing SMTP servers of all domains is basically DNS (MX records, each entry in MX record being an A record which resolves to IPv4/IPv6 address of the SMTP server). Can you elaborate more on what your requirement is? Also, MX records for a domain are dynamic and can change, so you shouldn't be caching those results into a database for more than DNS TTL as those might change on the fly in some cases.

Comment: `what do you want to use the SMTP servers addresses for?` I want to use the SMTP servers addresses to check if email adresse is valid.

Comment: `each entry in MX record being an A record which resolves to IPv4/IPv6 address of the SMTP server` , Do you mean that i make make a DNS query to get an A record?  And use the IPv4/IPv6 address of this A record as STMP server?

Comment: Finding 'A' Record of each entry in MX record get the IPv4/IPv6 address of the domain, not IPv4/IPv6 address of the SMTP server.

Comment: " I want to use the SMTP servers addresses to check if email adresse is valid" Don't bother then, it won't work. Servers will **obviously** not tell you which emails are good or not (if they did it means anyone - including spammers - would be able to finally get the whole list of emails handled on that server), the only way to test an email, besides obvious syntax problems, is to send an email with a nonce and expecting people to use that nonce.

Comment: As for the DNS step there are 2 ommissions or errors: per the standard hosts will first use `MX` records but then fallback to direct A/AAAA records if no `MX` and hence you need to test both. Then when you get the name, don't forget the legacy Internet should have died, so do not do just `A` queries but also `AAAA` (hoping that you have IPv6 connectivity of course otherwise this part is useless) to be in the current Internet.

Answer (score 0):

When one is trying to send an email out to a given recipient, we need to go through the following steps to pick a destination(this is not done by python's SMTPlib by default and is left for the user to choose the destination) -

1. Lookup the `MX` record of the recipient domain
2. The `MX` records of a domain can include multiple entries each with a specified priority
3. Each entry in the `MX` record is either an `A`(IPv4) or `AAAA`(IPv6) record
4. The sender is supposed to first *TRY* the `MX` record with the least priority if it doesn't connect/is not reachable, move on to the next entry in the MX records.
5. If a domain doesn't have `MX` records, try to query the `A` or `AAAA` records of the domain, if they exist use those for sending email.

e.g. for your domain in question, it has two MX record entries, and each of those has 2 `A` records -

```
~ # dig MX free.fr +short
10 mx1.free.fr.
20 mx2.free.fr.

~ # dig A mx1.free.fr. +short
212.27.48.7
212.27.48.6
~ # dig A mx2.free.fr. +short
212.27.42.59
212.27.42.58
```

Here we are supposed to try the `mx1.free.fr.` addresses first, if those don't connect move on to connect to the `mx2.free.fr.` addresses.

This should be pretty straight-forward using `dnspython` as you are doing now, but instead of re-inventing the wheel since you want to use this for validating the email addresses you can use this [py3-validate-email](https://pypi.org/project/py3-validate-email/) module, which already does what you want.

```
from validate_email import validate_email
is_valid = validate_email(
    email_address='example@example.com',
    check_format=True,
    check_blacklist=False,
    check_dns=True,
    dns_timeout=10,
    check_smtp=True,
    smtp_timeout=10,
    smtp_helo_host='put your reverse hostname',
    smtp_from_address='your sender address for test email',
    smtp_skip_tls=False,
    smtp_tls_context=None,
    smtp_debug=False)
```

This validation can also be slow, since we need to do multiple DNS queries, connect to the SMTP server, validate the recipient etc.(if some query times out it might take up to timeout for you to get the "invalid reciepient" verdict).

Also note that, a lot of receiving SMTP servers, have checks based on the EHLO hostname, PTR record of your sending IP etc, and if those are not valid, they might disconnect during SMTP even though the user might be valid. So this checking of - if the user is valid by attempting to connect to the SMTP server by trying to send an email to him/her might not always be the best idea.

Comment: Thank you for your explanations.
But it is impossible to initiate an SMTP conversation on `mx1.free.fr` or `mx2.free.fr`.
With `py3-validate-email`, I have the following error: `11:26:00.184002 connect: to ('mx1.free.fr', 25) None`

Comment: However, I notice that I can initiate an SMTP conversation on `smtp.free.fr` with `smtplib.SMTP_SSL(...)`.

Comment: It might have to do with your IP reputation/reverse DNS hostname, and the server might not be allowing you to connect to it. e.g. if I connect from my IP using
`nc -C mx1.free.fr 25`, I get `The IP XX.XX.XX.XX is blacklisted on Spamhaus PBL`

You can try running the SMTP commands manually and check if you can connect and try to send email. You can also try `validate_email_or_fail()` method from the lib to see what the error is.